# Joomla Extension AcySMS Need to modify source code

Tags: php, html, css, joomla

> hello all i need to change the style of Joomla extension AcySMS but
>   unable to find where i need to change

[image]

> here is actual problem i need to change the style so that button must
>   in front of text box and in country code selection i need to add
>   county code with the flag of country Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, please update your question so that it shows all **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: i don't know where is its code in extension actually i  just want to know where is actual code of this portion editing i will done

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this specific Joomla-extension, but you seem to need two changes:

- change the markup of the button
- place the button before the input

The first can be done by changing your own custom css-file. Use firebug or developer tools to find out which classes are used and override or extend them in your own css-file.

For the second one, you need to know whether you're using a plugin, a module or a component. The answer to this question leads you to the right Joomla-subfolder. There you will probably find a acysms-folder. Then you'll have to look (even in subfolders) for a file called default.php.

You should use template overrides to manipulate these files, otherwise your changes will be lost with the next regular update of this extension. You can search the Joomla website for help on template overrides. It's not very complicated. https://docs.joomla.org/How_to_override_the_output_from_the_Joomla!_core

If (for example) you want to make changes to the mod_login module then you would have to copy the file `default.php` from 
`PATH_TO_JOOMLA/modules/mod_login/tmpl/`
to
`PATH_TO_JOOMLA/TEMPLATE_NAME/html/mod_login/`
and apply your changes there.

I hope this will get you started.

Comment: i done using the following file changes `administrator/components/com_acysms/types/country.php` `administrator/components/com_acysms/gateway/bulksms/gateway.php` `plugins/system/acysmsverifnumber/acysmsverifnumber.php` `plugins/acysms/joomlauser/joomlauser.php` `administrator/components/com_acysms/extensions/plg_system_acysmsverifnumber/acysmsverifnumber.php`